# retrieving email with date and time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small form, everything works great with one small issue for some reason. When you receive an email from the form the date won't show in the email sent how ever it shows and is sent to the database.. the ip shows in the email no problem.

```
$message = "Welcome\n\n\n\nThank you for registering, if you have received this email then you have successfully created your new account. This message was sent from an unmonitored account. Any responses will not be read.\n\nRequest made from: " . $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
' on ' . $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

$additional_headers = "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\nContent-Type: text/plain";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the date doesn't appear in the email is that particular line isn't connected to anything.

```
$message = "Welcome\n\n\n\nThank you for registering, if you have received this email then you have successfully created your new account. This message was sent from an unmonitored account. Any responses will not be read.\n\nRequest made from: " . $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        ' on ' . $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

should be:

```
$message = "Welcome\n\n\n\nThank you for registering, if you have received this email then you have successfully created your new account. This message was sent from an unmonitored account. Any responses will not be read.\n\nRequest made from: " . $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " on " . $date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

You have a semicolon after the IP part, and your date isn't concatenated onto the string. Echoing out your `$message` variable with a fake IP currently returns this:

> Welcome Thank you for registering, if you have received this email
>   then you have successfully created your new account. This message was
>   sent from an unmonitored account. Any responses will not be read.
>   Request made from: 0.0.0.0

and with my code suggestion it returns:

> Welcome Thank you for registering, if you have received this email
>   then you have successfully created your new account. This message was
>   sent from an unmonitored account. Any responses will not be read.
>   Request made from: 0.0.0.0 on 2015/12/26 14:59:56

PS: I also changed your `'` characters towards the end into `"`, consistency improves readability.